# unTappd API getting the access token

Tags: reactjs, api, untappd

I am trying to get the unTappd API token. I have never tried to get an API access token before. So please bear with the simplicity of the question. I have been given the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET. How do I get the access token?

I have seen some information online using other languages aside from React. The function in my code works as it pulls random data fine and displays it. I just need the access token and I can get the unTappd information.

The documentation is here. [DOCS](https://docs.business.untappd.com/#introduction)

Comment: I'd guess you either 1) get them from the website https://business.untappd.com/api_tokens or 2) there's an oauth2 login endpoint somewhere you can use with an oauth client library? Usually client_id and secret identify your app or website and not the user / business account which is why you need the separate token.

Comment: Or you can get it from the API too: see 'POST /sessions' on the docs page, which is a username and password login.

Comment: Yes how do I do that? I have tried and tried and no luck. Where do I insert that code? Is it a terminal command? <https://docs.business.untappd.com/#post-sessions> That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Yes, curl is a terminal command and is usually installed everywhere (including Windows) nowadays, and the \ s are line continuations so it's simplest to edit those out but put everything on the same line. You can also just make a POST request instead from your code if that's easier - post the `-d` string as the message body (without the surrounding quotes) - or there are GUIs you can use to experiment with web APIs such as Postman.

Comment: I ran that and my email and login are incorrect. So I have found the issue emailed the untappd my query. Thank you for the help. I used PostMan.